# Packaging for the Ubuntu Software Center

Tags: software-center, packaging

I have a question about packaging for the Ubuntu Software Center: must the package to upload be a .deb file? If so, how do I create one? I don't use the pygobject API.

Comment: Check the website: http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/tools/packaging/

Answer (score 0):

No, give them whatever you have. They'll help you get it packaged.